# Using multiple email via Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I have had a Gmail account for years. Now I have bought a domain which I set up with Google Apps and want to use a couple of email addresses for one Gmail account.

I have email addresses like:

```
contact@mydomain.com //setup by Google Apps
mymail@gmail.com
support@mydomain.com
```

I want to use one email account to send/receive those multiple emails. When a email comes to `contact@mydomain.com` and I reply to the receiving end the mail should still be received from `contact@mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go into "Mail Settings" and click on the "Accounts and Import" tab, you will see a section where it says "Send mail as" and you can add any and all emails you wish to send from. Add your emails, and forward your other accounts to that email as well.

The downside of doing this is that, when you send an email from the central account, it will tell the recipient as such.

**For example:** you use the @gmail account as your central, and forward everything to it. When you send emails from contact@mydomain, it will say "contact@mydomain.com sent by mymail@gmail.com" or something to that effect.

It's been a while since I've used it like that, so perhaps they have changed it. Give it a shot and find out!

Comment: +1: I do it this way too. Google's official send mail instructions are [here.](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=22370) Forwarding email from a yourdomain.com address to your Gmail account is the fastest (and best) way to get it to appear in Gmail, but you can also set up [Mail Fetcher](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=21289) to check other mailboxes if you prefer. And yes, people you send email to via Gmail using a yourdomain.com from address can see your gmail.com account name in the email header, but this isn't a big deal for most users.

Comment: worked perfectly. I think the via in the subject is not shows anymore. Thanks!